# How can I save an image generated in python using PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to generate images with PIL and to save them. Unfortunately, i keep getting this error and i don't know why, i'm kind of new to PIL and image processing in general. I tried looking on the internet for answers but i couldn't find any, or at least i couldn't find any that works for me. I think it's a pretty simple code, there's just a problem of permissions and i don't know how i could solve it

```
  File "c:\Users\natha\Pictures\nft\py\script.py", line 49, in <module>
    fct()
  File "c:\Users\natha\Pictures\nft\py\script.py", line 45, in fct
    img.save("image.png")
  File "c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2209, in save  
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'image.png'
```

And here is my code :

```
from PIL import Image as i
import random

def random_number():
    nb = random.randrange(10)
    match nb:
        case 0:
            color = "#f84949"
        case 1:
            color = "#86feaa"
        case 2:
            color = "#86c4fe"
        case 3:
            color = "#f6fe86"
        case 4:
            color = "#fe8686"
        case 5:
            color = "#77ff5c"
        case 6:
            color = "#dbdbdb"
        case 7:
            color = "#d970ff"
        case 8:
            color = "#ffffff"
        case 9:
            color = "#ffa55c"
        case 10:
            color = "#99ccff"

    return color

def fct():
    img = i.new("RGB", (10000,10000), random_number())
    k = 0
    l = 0
    while k < 10000:
        while l < 100:
            lay = i.new("RGB", (100,100), random_number())
            img.paste(lay, (k,l*100))
            k = k + 100
            if k == 10000:
                k = 0
                l = l + 1
                if l == 100:
                    img.save("image.png")
                    return 1
    

fct()
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're saving image in C folder which does not have permission in this path. Try to save it in D drive in a folder and it will work. Also you can run your program as administrator and test it. Finally check and allow permissions of folder `c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\`  and set everyone full access, it will work.

Comment: that's nonsense, @Hamed_gibago we don't know what the current working directory of the script is. that determines where a relative path like `image.png` will be placed.

Comment: @nathan show how you execute the script. current working directory is especially important to know.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the script is in my Images folder on the C: drive, and i execute it using vscode

Comment: @Hamed_gibago i'll try that when i get home and i'll tell u

Comment: `print("CWD is:", repr(os.getcwd()))` in your script, run it as you do, see the path

Comment: Puting the script in the D folder worked, thanks !